# File transfer indicator applet?

Tags: unity, gnome, software-recommendation, indicator

In gnome-shell when you do a file transfer you get a icon appear in the bar at the top,

I know in unity it shows you the information in the unity Launcher, but I have that set to autohide, so I was wondering if there was a indicator that added the icon the the top panel bar like gnome-shell does?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but a [launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/indicator-transfer) has been started and if you get in now, you might get to influence its features...

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!